# monacaのiosのデバッガとプロジェクトのcordovaバージョン相違の警告を解消するには？

Tags: ios, monaca

デバッガでプロジェクトの起動時、以下のような警告が発生するのですが、
解消の方法はないでしょうか。
この警告が原因かは現時点で不明ですが、デバッグ起動しない状態です。

「プロジェクトのCordovaバージョンがデバッガーと一致しないため、正常に
動作しない可能性があります。」

プロジェクトのバージョン：3.5.1　または4.1.0
　（バージョンの切り替えは上記２バージョンのみ可能だったため）
ios8にインストールしたデバッガのバージョン：3.7.0
　（2015.3.29時点、最新verのデバッガです）

Comment: ios8にインストールしたデバッガのバージョンが3.7.0となっていますが、現在iOSにてインストール可能なAppStoreで配信されているバージョンの最新は3.2.0です。ビルドして使用するタイプのカスタムデバッガーの最新でも3.1.1ですが、3.7.0とはどのアプリの事でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

このエラーが過去に出ていたことがありますが、私の場合は、MonacaのダッシュボードでプロジェクトをCordova 2.9からCordova 3.5にアップデートすることで解決しました。また、Siegさんが仰るようにMonacaデバッガーの最新版は3.2.0です。 (2015年4月3日現在)

tuchiさんのプロジェクトのCordovaバージョンは本当に2.9ではないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

横から失礼します。

> ios8にインストールしたデバッガのバージョン：3.7.0
>   　（2015.3.29時点、最新verのデバッガです）

デバッガのバージョンは3.2.0、デバッガの左上の三本マークから「その他」>「デバッガ情報」で確認できるCordovaバージョンが3.7.0ということですね。

App Store で Monaca Debugger の 3.2.0 の「新機能」を見ると、2015/01/24時点で「Cordova 4.1.2ベースにアップデートしました」と書かれています。なのに「その他」>「デバッガ情報」では 3.7.0 とあるので、私も全く意味が分かりません。

私はプレビューでは動くのにデバッガーでは動いたり動かなかったり（なにやらタイムラグがあるような動作をする）という状態で悩んでいます。

まず「プロジェクトのCordovaバージョンがデバッガーと一致しないため、正常に動作しない可能性があります。」を解消して、Cordovaバージョンが問題なのかそうでないのかの切り分けをしたいです。

Monaca内部の皆様、このバージョンの差異について確認していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: Monacaの開発者がここを見てくれるとは限りませんから、必要であれば直接問い合わせたほうがよいかと。